# loading chart from data fetched using ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqplot

I am using jqPlot javascript library ( http://www.jqplot.com/ ) for graphs and charts in one of my application.

In my application, there are 5-6 pages where this library is used. But I would like to discuss one particular case here.

On 1 of page, I am loading 3 charts. Data for these 3 charts is populated from database tables.

There is different set of queries for each chart. So, populated data for each chart is different too.

Once I have populated data, I have to process it, before providing its input to chart.

**What is the problem then:**
Problem that I am facing is it takes lots of time for page to render on browser (which is quiet obvious, as first it will form query, then fire that query against database tables, get the data, process on data and give to chart)

One of my friend suggested to implement following thing using ajax. I really liked his solution.

This is what I intend to do:

I would create a page, which will load all the required js/css files for jqPlot library.
There will be 3 sections on that page, where I would put some GIF images indicating that some process is going on (say ajax-loader.gif)

Once page is loaded, it will fire 3 ajax call, one at a time, to fetch each chart.

**My Question Is** how can I load chart from data received from ajax-call?

jqplot puts data and creates chart in following way (look at example below)

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  var plot2 = $.jqplot ('chart2', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]], {
      // Give the plot a title.
      title: 'Plot With Options',
      // You can specify options for all axes on the plot at once with
      // the axesDefaults object.  Here, we're using a canvas renderer
      // to draw the axis label which allows rotated text.
      axesDefaults: {
        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
      },
      // An axes object holds options for all axes.
      // Allowable axes are xaxis, x2axis, yaxis, y2axis, y3axis, ...
      // Up to 9 y axes are supported.
      axes: {
        // options for each axis are specified in seperate option objects.
        xaxis: {
          label: "X Axis",
          // Turn off "padding".  This will allow data point to lie on the
          // edges of the grid.  Default padding is 1.2 and will keep all
          // points inside the bounds of the grid.
          pad: 0
        },
        yaxis: {
          label: "Y Axis" 
        }
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just another idea (and this ins't a solution, just a thought on how I would of done it if I hadn't had an idea), I would have used a php side library that rendered out the graphs as pictures.  The included images would load after the page, and wouldn't require any javascript (good for backwards compatibility), and you could include the graphs anywhere.

Comment: Remember: if an answer solves your problem, then "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark next to the answer. If you find an answer helpful (including answers to other people's questions), then click the "plus" arrow for the answer.

Comment: Hey Did you put loader in jqplot???can u please help on that...i want to put ajax loader unitll chart is fully loaded with data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you'd use the [jQuery Ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to fetch the chart data after the page has loaded.

In your `success` function, your JS code (on the browser) receives the data from your server. Once you have the data, make the call to `$.jqplot` -- passing in the data you've just received.

To initially show the busy gif, just use the img element as the static content of the `chart2` div which will later be the graph's container.

Some tips:

- Some browsers don't do well at handling an animated gif while running a js program. So you may want to try a text message ("Loading chart...") in addition to the rotating gif. -- Or update the text messages. Eg start with "Fetching chart data from server" then update to "Processing chart data" once your `success` function has been called.
- Rather than starting all 3 Ajax calls at once, experiment with having the `success` function for the first chart initiating the second Ajax call. (In addition to it charting the data.)

If you have problems with your Ajax calls, Google for examples and ask a separate question on SO if you still have problems.

Comment: I still have some doubt. As per your answer, once I have data, I have to make a call to $.jqplot. First argument to $.jqplot is element name ( in my case it would be div element ), and if you again check example in question, you can see that element is named 'chart2'. Should I have that element already on page, or can be added on fly.

Comment: You can either add the container element on the fly (dynamically) or you can start the page with the container element (the div) already there. If you already know that the page will always contain 3 charts then just start with divs already in the starting html page, it's easier.

Comment: Also, it is easier to put the feedback message ("loading") in the container element. That way the chart library will automatically take care of removing the loading message once the chart is displayed. (If it doesn't, then change the loading msg to be display:none once the chart is displayed.)